# Dart Analyzer: Find instances of a class or its descendants

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer, dart-build

I am using the `build` package to take a `.dart` file and look for definitions of a certain class or its subclasses. Can [`ClassElement`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/analyzer/latest/dart_element_element/ClassElement-class.html) be used for subclasses too?

I am only expecting a single definition of a specific class to be within one file of the project, but there's no reason clients couldn't subclass and go wild.

Comment: I think that should work using the `allSupertypes` method. https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen/blob/master/source_gen/lib/src/type_checker.dart might help. See also how its used in https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/search?q=typechecker&unscoped_q=typechecker

Comment: I made a suggested edit to the question - normally when we talk about classes an "instance" means an object created with `new NameOfType();`. I think what you're looking for here are class "definitions" or "subclasses".

Comment: I actually was looking for an instance to be able to call `toString()` on it. I am just using a workaround where I give an example usage and people can copy it. No analyzer needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to directly grab all subclasses, but you can find all classes and check if each one is a subclass of the one you're interested in.

Start by getting the `LibraryElement` for the file you're generating code for with [`BuildStep.inputLibrary`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/build/0.12.7/build/BuildStep/inputLibrary.html). From there find all the classes in the library with `var classes = libraryElement.units.expand((cu) => cu.types);`. Then check if each one is a subclass of the class you are interested in by checking whether the `ClassElement` for the type you are interested in is in [`ClassElement.allSupertypes`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/analyzer/0.33.0-alpha.0/dart_element_element/ClassElement/allSupertypes.html) for the type you are checking. `var subtypes = classes.where((c) => c.allSupertypes.contains(lookingFor));`.

You may find the [`LibraryReader`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/source_gen/0.9.0/source_gen/LibraryReader-class.html) and [`TypeChecker`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/source_gen/0.9.0/source_gen/TypeChecker-class.html) utilities from `source_gen` useful.

Comment: What if the subclasses are inside different libraries (files, usually)?

Comment: I'm not aware of an efficient way to find them. The build system (and the analyzer's use within) doesn't have a notion of "full program", only the code reachable via imports of whatever file you are running on. Most likely you'd need to run a builder with the primary input being the "entrypoint" (that has a main()) and then walk over all transitive imports.